# How to DROP table in correct order in SQL SERVER 2014?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have following 5 tables and 1 table is connected as Foreign key in 2 tables. My dilemma is that I cannot figure out which table to drop first. below is the drop table code I am trying and I have created tables in following order

**Updated  Drop Table Code:**

```
 IF EXISTS (SELECT*FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME='[Student Major]')
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE [Student Major]
    END
    GO
    IF EXISTS (SELECT*FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME='Major')
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE Major
    END
    GO
    IF EXISTS (SELECT*FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME='Citizenship')
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE Citizenship
    END
    GO
    IF EXISTS (SELECT*FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME='Country')
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE Country
    END
    IF EXISTS (SELECT*FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME='Student')
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE Student
    END
    GO
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE Student(
    [Student ID] INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
    ,[First Name] varchar (50) NOT NULL
    ,[Last Name] varchar (30) NOT NULL
    )
GO

CREATE TABLE Country(
    [Country ID] int identity PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
    ,[Country of Birth] varchar (10)
    ,[Student ID] int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Student([Student ID]) NOT NULL
    )
GO

CREATE TABLE Citizenship(
    [Citizenship ID] int identity PRIMARY KEY
    ,[Country of Citizenship1] varchar (10)
    ,[Country of Citizenship2] varchar (10)
    ,[Student ID] int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Student([Student ID]) NOT NULL
    ,[Country ID] int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Country([Country ID]) NOT NULL
    )
GO
CREATE TABLE Major(
    [Major ID] int identity PRIMARY KEY
    ,[Major Name] varchar(30) NOT NULL
    )
GO

CREATE TABLE [Student Major](
    [Student MajorID] int identity 
    ,[Student ID] int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Student([Student ID])
     ,[Major ID] int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Major([Major ID])
     ,[Graduated Major] varchar (30) NOT NULL
    )
GO
```

I Would like to drop table in correct order

Errors:
Could not drop object 'Student' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.
Also,Please provide explanation of dropping the table. I am new to SQL.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Separately, your data model is flawed in that it allows only one student per country. You should probably add CountryID to the Student table as a a foreign key to Country and remove StudentID from Country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 DROP TABLE Student_Major; GO 
   SELECT 1 FROM Citizenship; GO
 DROP TABLE Citizenship; GO
   SELECT 1 FROM Major; GO
 DROP TABLE Major; GO
   SELECT 1 FROM Country; GO
 DROP TABLE Country; GO
   SELECT 1 FROM Student; GO
 DROP TABLE Student; GO
```

It's just like you said, it has to be in the order so that any table that is referenced by a FK is not dropped, as long as the FK is there.

EDIT: `GO` forces the end of the batch

EDIT: I notice you have the `GO` in there already.  You could use Information_schema to find the constraints associated with the table and drop them first, but I feel like you shouldn't need to do that.  What if you injected a dummy query imbetween each `DROP` statement.  It's hacky but if you don't feel like having to understand all the information_schema stuff it might be easier if it works.

Comment: I tried above code in "Updated Drop table section" it is still giving me an error Msg 3726, Level 16, State 1, Line 59 Could not drop object 'Major' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint. Msg 3726, Level 16, State 1, Line 73 Could not drop object 'Student' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint " Any suggestion what could be the reason ?

Comment: Actually I would just go with Rodrick's answer

Comment: I agreed wit your comment, But I dont't know the order that I can use I tried reversing the order, but didn't work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nice how about an upvote for helping you troubleshoot haha

Answer (score 4):

Here is the way that I usually do it:

```
SELECT      'ALTER TABLE [' + O.[name] + '] DROP ' + F.[name]
FROM        sys.objects O 
INNER JOIN  sys.foreign_keys F ON (F.parent_object_id = O.object_id)
WHERE       O.[type] = 'U'


SELECT      'DROP TABLE [' + [name] + ']'
FROM        sys.objects
WHERE       [type] = 'U'
ORDER BY    create_date DESC
```

This will generate a record set such as

```
ALTER TABLE Foo DROP FK_BLAH
ALTER TABLE Bar DROP FK_BAH

...

DROP TABLE Foo
DROP TABLE Bar
```

Which, you can then just copy and paste into a query window, and run from there.

<sup>(At the time that I'm writing this answer, I don't have access to an instance of SQL server, but I use code like the above all the time.)</sup>

Comment: Just quick question. So how would I find the order of my tables ?. i can see that above code generated 2nd Codes presented by you .

Comment: @biggboss2019 -- I added a "`order by create_date desc`" clause to the query for dropping tables. That should sort them in reverse of the order that you created them.

Answer (score 1):

You could first remove all FK constraints by:

```
 ALTER TABLE ... DROP CONSTRAINT ...;
```

Then drop tables in any order.

---

If you are using `SQL Server 2016` and above you could use `DIE`(drop if exists) and multiple tables at-once (still order matters):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [Student Major], Major, Citizenship, Country,Student;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=68d882aaba36a7bebebdf1c7b738347a)**

Answer (score 0):

If you are in doubt, and don't want to remove your constraints for some reason, you can always **drop your tables in the exact opposite order in which you created them**.

Since the *first* table doesn't reference any other, but maybe is referenced by other tables created after it, you should delete it *last*.

For the remaining tables, apply same logic. The first of the remaining tables is to be deleted last among them, and so on.

Comment: I tried the above "updated drop table" code and it is still giving me an error saying "Msg 3726, Level 16, State 1, Line 59
Could not drop object 'Major' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.
Msg 3726, Level 16, State 1, Line 73
Could not drop object 'Student' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint "

Comment: The order of creation of the tables might not be correlated with the order of the foreign key creation